# File loader img, webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Всем привет. 
Проблема с вебпаком. 
Есть лоадер для изображений.

```
{
                    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                    exclude: /fonts/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                                outputPath: 'images/',
                                publicPath: '../images/' // use relative urls
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                            options: {
                                bypassOnDebug: ! isProduction,
                                mozjpeg: {
                                    progressive: true,
                                    quality: 65
                                },
                                optipng: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                pngquant: {
                                    quality: '65-90',
                                    speed: 4
                                },
                                gifsicle: {
                                    interlaced: false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Проблема заключается в следующем. 
При сборке проекта,  изображения,  что  прописанные в  html файле не правильно записываются.
На пример. 
В исходном файле

```
<img src="images/bg.png">
```

В собранном будет так

```
<img src="../images/bg.png">
```

При том,  что в css файле все правильно. 
Как правильно настроить? 
Пример всего конфига находиться [тут](https://pastebin.com/VGgYVHAm)

Пример структуры проекта:

src/

- images/
- styles/

  - app.scss
- index.html

Comment: вы сами указали publicPath: '../images/'

Comment: @Александр да, но если изменить тут, то тогда в сss будет не правильно прописывать пути.